# Translating Chinese

Tags: translation

I have this exchange student next to me and last week I saw a friend of hers write something on her door and they seemed to have quite a lot of fun about it. Can someone translate it or at least say what it's about? Everyone is very curious about it but no one ever sees her to ask or is afraid to ask.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I self-answer "What does this say?"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/36144/how-do-i-self-answer-what-does-this-say)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the phrases are internet languages. Just “baidu” it and you will know.

For example

> 木有: 没有
>
> 正房生快：
>
> 正房 primary wife. In old days in China, man can have a wife and many
>   concubines.
>
> 生快 is shorted for 生日快乐（happy birthday）

Comment: It's a bit hard for non-native speakers to write or type chinese without understanding the sounds associated with the symbols. I suppose the OP  may have that issue. I figured out how to trace the image using the trackpad on the Mac. OCR almost never works.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem I had. I used a site where you can draw symbols and it tries to recognize it but I didn't find a single symbol.

Comment: We can use this tool. You draw and it tells you the sound. http://jingyan.baidu.com/article/636f38bb5d70e7d6b84610c7.html
  Now native speakers, especially young generations like me, dominantly use sounds to type cause we are forgetting how to write（提笔忘字）, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

白象代表方便面和巧克力："white elephant" denotes instant noodles and chocolate. "白象" is a instant noodles brand in China.

好久没见（Long time no see）蓝天（blue sky）白云（white clouds）太阳（sun）了.

Answer (score 1):

1.I haven't seen a sunny day for a long time(maybe you are in Britian),so he draws clouds and sun in the top if the picture and want a sunny day.

2.I wish my primary wife a happy birthday(referring to the exchange student who live in this room)that means he or she is joking about the owner is the primary wife and the unspoken words means the drawer has many other wives,of coure joking.

3."晴天娃娃" means the picture above,maybe the drawer nikname]
"祝"=wish
"老牛"=old cow(maybe refer to your friend live in the house)

6.the drawer feels too complicated to draw the cow so he draws an elephant instead.
"生快"=happy birday

4.5."白象"=white elephant(a Chinese inatant noodles brand)represents the instant noodles and chocolate as a birthday gift to her, also kind of joking.

All the picture shows a sense of humor to a friend's birthday and wish her happy birday.

[image]

Comment: About [晴天娃娃](http://zhidao.baidu.com/link?url=1WC--J6woNoW2cn6sq1waYOcioxaAV2D-2dWZ9uPnKoziMcUuAiUnX3I86pJHLHiRZlgzKOOkktpDCPovtXX7a)

Comment: Yes, and there's a picture of the tera bozu doll (see here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnXl9jNy7o0)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was her birthday last week and her friend wrote funny birthday messages on there! (See other replies)

Answer (score 0):

正房 primary wife. In old days in China, man can have a wife and many concubines.

生快 is short for 生日快乐（happy birthday）

很久没见蓝天白云太阳了 long time no seeing blue sky, white clouds, and the Sun

晴天娃娃 Sunny Baby

祝老牛 wish you the Old Cow

木有烦恼 having no worries

天天灿烂 every day resplendent

不会画老牛 don't know how to draw a cow

来个象代替 drew an elephant instead

白象代表方便面和巧克力 the while elephant represents instant noodles and chocolates

算礼物了 that would be my presents

哈哈 haha

分割线 dividing line